# Write all the components of a matrix as a vector seperated by tab and comma alternatively

Tags: r

Let us consider a matrix **C** with 7 rows and 2 column, where the columns are

```
x=c(0.018,0.021,0.006,-0.018,-0.021,-0.006,0.018)
y=c(-0.017,0.002,0.027,0.0179,-0.002,-0.027,-0.017)
C=cbind(x,y)
```

I want to write **C** as **C'** where

```
C'=(0.018 -0.017,0.021 0.002,0.006 0.027,-0.018 0.017,-0.021-0.002,-0.006 -0.027,0.018 -0.017)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x1 <- toString(paste(C[,1], C[,2], collapse = ','))
#[1] "0.018 -0.017,0.021 0.002,0.006 0.027,-0.018 0.0179,-0.021 -0.002,-0.006 -0.027,0.018 -0.017"
```

To get it without quotations,

```
print(x1, quote = FALSE)
#[1] 0.018 -0.017,0.021 0.002,0.006 0.027,-0.018 0.0179,-0.021 -0.002,-0.006 -0.027,0.018 -0.017
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't want the double quotation marks in output. How to do that?

Comment: The quotations are there because we are converting it to a character string. How are you planning to use it?

Comment: Want to use as the argument of POLYGON in the following line: readWKT("POLYGON ((0.018 -0.017, 0.02 0.002,0.0060 .027, -0.018 0.017, -0.02 -0.002,-0.006 -0.027,0.018 -0.017))")

Comment: This function is there in the Package ‘rgeos’.

Comment: another way to try is `noquote(x1)`

Comment: That's fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question as asking for a vector of numbers, the quickest way is to just call `as.numeric` on the `t`ransposition of `C`:

```
as.numeric(t(C))
# [1]  0.0180 -0.0170  0.0210  0.0020  0.0060  0.0270 -0.0180  0.0179 -0.0210 -0.0020 -0.0060
# [12] -0.0270  0.0180 -0.0170
```

This works by transposing `C`, i.e. flipping its *i* and *j* dimensions, so it looks like:

```
t(C)
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]    [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]
# x  0.018 0.021 0.006 -0.0180 -0.021 -0.006  0.018
# y -0.017 0.002 0.027  0.0179 -0.002 -0.027 -0.017
```

`as.numeric` then drops the dimension information that makes a matrix a matrix, reducing it to just a vector of numbers.

You could do the same thing on `C` untransposed, but since matrices are filled by column by default, it will reverse in the same way, grabbing all the `x` values before all the `y`s instead of returning values by row. Transposing makes it read the values in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.